# Backbone.js inherited views

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone view hierachy as follows:

```
GenericView = Backbone.View.extend({
templatesPath: "source/public/templates/",
initialize: function(){
    var that = this;
    this.model.fetch({
        success: function(model,response){
            that.handleResponse(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("err");
        }
    });
}
```

});

and the view that extends the Generic view is:

```
FriendsView = GenericView.extend({
    url: "friends.php",
    el: $("fiends-list"),
    model: new Person(),
    initialize: function(){
        FriendsView.__super__.initialize.apply();
    },
    handleResponse: function(res){

    }
});
```

What I would like to do is to access the child view functions from the parent initialize function. I found a number of similar issues, but all where talking about it the other way around- accessing from the parent to the child, which I do at " 
FriendsView.**super**.initialize.apply();"-

the line :

```
this.model.fetch({...});
```

is saying that model is undefined, but I'm sure that the model is defined.

Comment: You should edit this question. The wording is confusing. Are you talking about view inheritance or nesting views (for example a list view that creates item views)? I thought the latter, but your code looks to be about inheritance.

Comment: Yes. Agree with Gohn67. I posted an answer, but still unsure if it's appropriate, since you talk about nested views but that doesn't seem to be what your sample is doing.

Comment: Your are correct. I'm fairly new to backbone, so got confused between nested views and inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child view needs to have been created either within the parent view's `initialize`, or prior to the instance of the parent view being created.

The issue with your model being undefined is due to you doing the following in your FriendsView:

```
initialize: function(){
    FriendsView.__super__.initialize.apply();
}
```

You're calling initialize on GenericView, but not an INSTANCE of GenericView.  The definition doesn't have a `this.model`.

Note, the below sample might be completely useless, but I'm going off your description of a parent and child view.  If this is wrong, please inform me.

I'd be doing something like:

```
ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.childView = new FriendView({ parentView: self });

        //do other init things here.
    },
    fetchModel: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.model.fetch({
                success: function(model,response){
                that.childView.handleResponse(response);
            },
            error: function(){
            console.log("err");
        }
    }
});
FriendsView = GenericView.extend({
     initialize: function (opts) {
         this.parentView = opts.parentView;
         this.parentView.fetchModel();
     }
});
```

**However**
Wouldn't it be easier to just have your model in the childView?  Or use events to listen for changes, rather than initiating changes across different entities?

```
ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.childView = new FriendView({ model: this.model });
     //do your other things here
    },
    //other functions
```

Now when you want to handle the response in the childView, you can just have an event for that like:

```
FriendsView = GenericView.extend({
     initialize: function (opts) {
         this.listenTo(this.model,'sync',this.handleResponse)
         this.model.fetch({
              error:function () {
                  console.log("err");
              }
         });
     }
});
```

That way, regardless of where fetch is called, you can get the event.  Even if you called it from the parentView, because the child and parent are looking at the same model.

Comment: That did accomplish what I wanted, but not sure what you mean with having my model in the childView. I think the question is not all that clear. What I wanted was to fetch all the data that I wanted when the page loads. And the easiest way I could think of was to do it when initializing the views. But I also wanted code reusability, so thought of creating this inheritance structure. 
 Now the bottom line is that I got what I need :D thank you.

Comment: WhaT I mean by having your model in the childview is, when you instantiate your child, just pass the child the model. See edit.